# Set a Domain Name as a DNS

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns, dynamic-ip, ddns

I am hosting a DNS from my Raspberry Pi and would like to set it as my primary DNS in Windows 10. However I do not have a Static IP Address and would like to use my DDNS to connect to my DNS. For example when using nslookup I would do

> nslookup example.com mydns.net

How am I able to use mydns.net as my DNS, in Windows 10.

Comment: And how is the system supposed to resolve that DNS name?

Comment: @grawity I see the issue there. Is it possible to use a DNS to resolve the name and then the DNS for all other look-ups.

Comment: No.  But your Pi should have a static IP on your LAN.  Just use that IP.

Comment: @ivanivan am using a VPN that doesn't allow for local DNS and would also like to use my DNS outside of the house.

Comment: Use a public DNS server to look up your dynamic IP, then put it into `/etc/resolv.conf`.